# HTML to servlet communication without form tag

Tags: java, servlets

Actually I am displaying name dynamically from my database. What I am not getting is that "after retrieving name from a database that is dynamic data. For this 'Name' I need to provide a link" that should display details regarding database table content of 'name' contained table.

Please help me.

Comment: You can use a query part of the URL, something like `/details?id=...` where you pass the id of the record.

Comment: Did we solve your problem? If so, please pick an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

> Html to servlet Communication without form tag

Regardless the communication is being happen through a `Form`, it is essentially a `GET` or `POST` request. Look up for that to understand that better.

> For this 'Name' I need to provide a link" that should display Details regarding Database Table content of 'name' Contained Table.

If I undertood you well, you should create a link that, when clicked, should open a new page with the Details, right?

You can generate a link similar to this:

```
<a href='http://www.yourwebsite.com/DetailsServlet?id=X'>Show details</a>
```

Where `X` is the ID that would be retrieved on your sevlet (or JSP file):

```
public class DetailsServlet implements HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        // Get details based on ID and show the page
    }
}
```

After that, you only have to get the Details using that ID and then show them in another page.

A fancier alternative would involve AJAX, but you should really stick to the basics in your state.

Answer (score 1):

Keep that name in  tag i.e the name should be between 'a' tag.
Suppose the name you are reading is in 'DbName' field in  tag give like

```
 <a href="somepage.jsp?Name=DbName>DbName</a>
```

And Read That in somepage.jsp file like
      request.getParameter("Name");